# ¿Cómo saber si mi cadena contiene un carácter de otra cadena?

Tags: java

Lo que busco o quiero saber es si mi cadena tiene un valor diferente y mostrar que este mal por un valor no aceptado
Estas son mis variables y entrada por usuario

```
String cadena;  
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
String Alfabeto = "cdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyz"; 
System.out.println("Ingrese una cadena: "); 
cadena = sc.nextLine();
```

Aqui esta mi codigo

> ```
>     for (int i = 0; i<cadena.length(); i++){
>         if (cadena.contains("a") && cadena.contains("b")){
>             System.out.println("La cadena es valida");
>             break;
>         }else{
>             System.out.println("La cadena no es valida");
>             break;
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Cuando el usuario inserta babbb la cadena es valida pero cuando inserta babc la cadena no es valida ¿Como le puedo hacer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes resumir tu código a algo tan simple como:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String cadena = sc.nextLine();

if (cadena.matches("[ab]+")) {
    System.out.println("La cadena es valida");
} else {
    System.out.println("La cadena no es valida");
}
```

La expresión `[ab]+` matchea todas las cadenas que estén formadas SOLO por las letras minúsculas `a` y `b`. Por tanto  `cadena.matches("[ab]+")` devuelve `true` si la cadena está formada solo por a y b, de lo contrario, devuelve false. No necesitas un `for`.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, funciona :)